# Asp.net determine uploaded image black and white area %

Tags: c#, asp.net

is that possible build a asp.net application that able to determine uploaded image black and white area %?

EXAMPLE :
[image]

After user upload the picture ,the application will calculate the black and white area.

**Output :**

**White :**32%

**Black :**68%

Comment: It is definitely possible. Where exactly are you having trouble?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Bitmap` class. With the properties `Width` and `Height` you can calculate the total pixel count. And with the method `GetPixel` you can get the color of a specific pixel. To compare a known color like `Color.White` to an other color you can use the `ToArgb` method.

```
Image yourImage = ...

Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(yourImage);
int whiteColorCount = 0;
int blackColorCount = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < bitmap.Width; i++)
{
    for (int c = 0; c < bitmap.Height; c++)
    {
        int pixelHexColor = bitmap.GetPixel(i, c).ToArgb();
        if (pixelHexColor == Color.White.ToArgb())
        {
            whiteColorCount++;
        }
        else if (pixelHexColor == Color.Black.ToArgb())
        {
            blackColorCount++;
        }
    }
}

long totalPixelCount = bitmap.Width * bitmap.Height;
double whitePixelPercent = whiteColorCount / (totalPixelCount / 100.0);
double blackPixelPercent = blackColorCount / (totalPixelCount / 100.0);
double otherPixelPercent = 100.0 - whitePixelPercent - blackPixelPercent;
```

Comment: Image yourImage = Image.FromFile(FileUploadControl.FileName);
but getting this error :System.IO.FileNotFoundException: test.png

Comment: @KyLim Well the name of the exception is self-explanatory. Are you sure you are pointing to the correct path of the file? Maybe you are missing a `MapPath` so the code knows where to look.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can convert you image to Bitmap and use this method. It return number of pixel  your set  color .Get number of black and white pixels and calculate how many percent is black and white.

```
    // Return the number of matching pixels.
private int CountPxl(Bitmap bmap, Color yourColor)
{
// Loop through the pixels.
int matches = 0;
for (int y = 0; y < bmap.Height; y++)
{
for (int x = 0; x < bmap.Width; x++)
{
if (bmap.GetPixel(x, y) == yourColor) matches++;
}
}
return matches;
}
```